# Can youtubes Markdown syntax be escaped?

Tags: youtube, markdown

I'm trying to use literal double dash: `--` in youtube video description, and youtube's markdown formats subsequent text as strikethrough.

Note: the issue occurs when there are multiple occurances of strings containing `--`.

I've tried some common markdown escaping methods, suh as:

````
\--string
```--string```
````

To no avail, and with the nature of google and youtube every search I could concieve resulted in videos of markdown use in other languages. The only slightly relevent things I could find were guides on how to format text, none of which had information regarding escaping.

Comment: Do you edit your YouTube video description in YouTube studio ? Because when I try to add `--string` to [my YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWdFMNQBcjs) description, the text isn't strikethrough.

Comment: the issue occurs when there are multiple occurances of strings containing `--`. Question updated to reflect. Current workaround is to use an em dash in it's place and make Note that fact for viewers